# Wait until a new Sqlite event happens

Tags: php, database, sqlite, long-polling

I'd like PHP to wait and do an action when a new row has been inserted in a SQLite database.

Of course, we could do:

```
while (true) {
    usleep(200*1000);  // wait 200 ms
    $db->query('SELECT id ....');  // check if a new row (with a new id) has been inserted
}
```

but I'd like to avoid querying the database every 200 ms for nothing, because this would be a waste of resource.

Context: I want to do this in a long polling scheme, and avoid having a PHP worker / daemon running constantly: the client does a connection to the server, the server doesn't answer immeditately and wait until something new happens in the database.

Note: I have already used WebSocket in the past, but for this specific project, I cannot use it.

Comment: You can use [`PRAGMA data_version`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_data_version) instead of a select, btw.

Comment: This is quite a big ask: No polling, short or long, and no open connections. No WebSockets, for some unknown reason, and very little context to go on. It sounds like you're looking for the impossible.

Comment: I want to see if it's possible to react as soon as a new entry arrives in a database, but without having a central server/worker/daemon run from command-line with `php myserver.php`. Until something new happens, PHP should wait and not return anything to client. TL;DR I want to do this (long polling): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLnOU.png but without a daemon. I'd like the second blue arrow to happen when a new entry appears in the Sqlite database. Do you see what I mean @KIKOSoftware?

Comment: I think your safest bet is to use transaction on `insert`, `update`.  When the `commit` transaction is done you know the data is there, if `rollback` was not performed, is there.  You don't need  `select` to verify the value.

Comment: @tukan yes but this could happen in another PHP script/process than the one which is waiting here.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want. However, the second blue arrow is simply the response from the server with the javascript code for the long request. It's where the long polling starts. What you suggest simply shifts the long polling one step back, it doesn't change the basic procedure. You would still need a PHP script that looks for changes in the database.

Comment: Let's change things a bit: Do you have control over all the PHP scripts that could change your database? In other words: Could they initiate a process that signals the change?

Comment: That will, of course, depend how it is written.    You could try WAL (write-ahead logging) - https://sqlite.org/wal.html.  You could check the WAL file and do a `checkpoint` (time where the data moves from WAL file transactions into the database)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes they could, but I'm trying to design a tool (let's take a realtime "chat"  as an example), that works even on shared hosting where the user *only* has access to FTP files upload. The server can serve PHP (and AJAX of course), but PHP cannot spawn new processes; the user cannot use SSH command-line; the user cannot run a PHP daemon like `php myworker.php`, etc. so obviously they cannot use WebSockets that would need such a worker. I'm analysing the smallest tools necessary to do a PHP chat software that runs nearly *everywhere*.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I know that these constraints are difficult but that's the challenge: the tiny-tiny-tiniest chat software ;)

Answer (score 3):

You said that all PHP scripts, that could change your database, could initiate a process that would signal that change. This would mean you don't have to poll the database constantly, you could poll something else, something simple.

Let's say that every time a change was made to the database, a file, containing a time signal, would be updated. A PHP function, that could do that, would be:

```
function signalDatabaseChange()
{
    $success = FALSE;
    if ($file = fopen('signal.json', 'w')) 
    {
        $json = json_encode(["timeSignal" => hrtime(TRUE)]);
        if (flock($file, LOCK_EX)) {
            $success = fwrite($file, $json) > 0;
            flock($file, LOCK_UN); 
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    return $success;
}
```

It will write a tiny JSON file containing a time signal, while holding an exclusive blocking lock on the file. It returns `TRUE` when successful, otherwise `FALSE`. A `FALSE` response should be handled properly by your application.

So now we have a little JSON file on the server that signals the latest time the database changed. This file can be polled often while using very little resources.

You implied you wanted to use long polling. In that case have a look at [using server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

You can poll the `signal.json` in the PHP code with something like this:

```
function getTimeSignal()
{
    $timeSignal = FALSE;
    if ($file = fopen('signal.json', 'r')) 
    {
        if (flock($file, LOCK_SH)) {
            $json = fread($file, filesize('signal.json'));
            flock($file, LOCK_UN); 
            $timeSignal = json_decode($json);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    return $timeSignal;
}
```

This will return the stored time signal, or `FALSE`. By using file locking, in both functions, you are guaranteed there will always be a valid timestamp present in the file.

When the client has retrieved a new time signal it could use that, and the previous time signal it got, to ask the server for all the database changes that happened between those two signals.

This method assumes that there will be a lot more time signal checks than time signal updates. Only then it will be worth using this method.

I've used a file to store the time signal, but that's not the only option. The time signal could be stored in memory. In almost all cases this requires some control over the PHP configuration and I am not sure you have that, given all the constraints you've laid out.

In this example code I have used a time signal. This almost implies that your database also stores these time signals. That might not be the case. You could, of course, add them, but you could also use something else. I don't know what to suggest, but it could, for instance with a chat app, be the index of the latest chat message.