# Most Efficient Way To Poll Database Using SSE

Tags: php, mysql, server-sent-events

I feel like this must be a problem that's been solved a million times, but after three hours of searching, I can't find an answer. I'm trying to figure out how to send data to a client only when a change has occurred in a Mysql table, and do that in the most efficient way.

For a "Now Playing" function on a streaming audio player, I need to update a <DIV> tag with artist and song title data every time the song changes. I was using JQuery + Ajax to do this, but that seemed horribly inefficient, so I switched to server-sent events. My server-side code is below.

However, this seems only marginally more efficient because, unless my understanding is incorrect, my code sends the same artist - song data every five seconds, even if there's no change to the song on the air.

```
<?php

//include db connect file
if (!isset($pdo)) {
include '../../PDO_con.inc';
}

//run a query to get the most recent song for today
$statement = $pdo->query('[SELECT most recent record in table]');

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $artist = $row['artist_name'];
    $song   = $row['title'];
    $song_data = $artist . " - " . $song;

}

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo "retry: 5000\ndata: {$song_data}\n\n";
flush();

?>
```

It seems like I should run the select query over and over again every 5 seconds (maybe by wrapping it in a WHILE loop?), but only send SSE data when a change has occurred. I should be able to figure this out on my own, but the answer has thus-far eluded me. Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:** In response to a comment, here is the query that selects the most recent record:

```
'SELECT artist.artist_name, song.title, plays.play_date FROM plays INNER JOIN song ON plays.song_id = song.id INNER JOIN artist ON song.artist_id = artist.id WHERE date(plays.play_date) = date(now()) ORDER BY plays.play_date DESC LIMIT 1';
```

What I mean by efficiency is only sending data where there has been a change. Right now, my scripts sends data every 5 seconds whether it has changed or not. The <DIV> tag on the client side updates existing data with the same data until there has been a change. Thus, for a 1-minute song, the artist+title data is sent 12 times. It seems like this is a waste of internet resources, although I suppose it's possible that given the totality of internet traffic, it's a trivial waste.

Comment: you can use sockets to update whenever there is a change in the table after updating or inserting in a table

Comment: It would be good to understand what you mean by most efficient and also what is that query that selects the most recent entries.

Comment: I've [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978726/wait-until-a-new-sqlite-event-happens/66109840#66109840) 10 days ago, where I proposed to use a tiny file, instead of polling the database. I used a time signal there, but you could put the song data in that file. The idea isn't perfect, but at least you won't be polling the database constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have some way of identifying which records need to pushed to the client from the database you can poll the database at regular intervals. Depending on the complexity of your database design you might want to consider other optimizations e.g. cache.

You can perform an infinite loop that runs as long as the connection is open. Every 5 seconds you poll the database to see if there are any new entries. Keep track of the most recent one that you polled.

Here is a very crude example:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4", 'user', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

$lastTime = new DateTime('1 minute ago');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT message, created_at FROM messages WHERE created_at>? ORDER BY created_at');

while (!connection_aborted()) {
    $stmt->execute([$lastTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);

    foreach ($stmt as $message) {
        $lastTime = new DateTime($message['created_at']);
        echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $lastTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n\n";
    }

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(5);
}
```

Polling the database every 5 seconds is not that bad. An average user can refresh a page a few times a seconds, so your server should easily handle a poll every 5 seconds.